# Syntax error with defining pure function

Tags: haskell

Given the following function, I receive a parse error from GHC.

```
has_empty_string :: [String] -> Bool
has_empty_string col =
  not foldl (\acc now -> if and [acc == True, now == ""] then False else True) True col
```

I've checked a variety of tutorials and I don't see the error.

What is more confusing is that GHC takes it, when I prepend `let` to the definition.

---

Rewritten to use any_null.

I have a suspicion that the error is actually elsewhere...

```
module Main where
import System.Cmd
import System.Directory
import System.Environment
import System.IO
import System.Process
import Text.Regex.Posix
import Data.CSV.Enumerator
import Data.Spreadsheet

import Data.Char (isSpace)

--------------------------------------------------
slurp :: String -> IO String
slurp path = do
  withFile path ReadMode (\handle -> do
                             contents <- hGetContents handle
                             last contents `seq` return contents )

--------------------------------------------------
has_empty_string :: [String] -> Bool
has_empty_string col =
  any null

main :: IO ()
main = do
  [filename] <- getArgs
  raw_data <- slurp filename
  let csv_data = fromString '"' ',' raw_data
  -- checking to see if the 5th column is an empty string
  content_hashes = get_hashrow csv_data
                   where get_hashrow = map (\row -> row !! 5) csv_data
  is_good_csv = has_empty_hash content_hashes
  putStrLn $ show csv_data
```

Comment: @Krzysztof: Determine if the list of strings has an empty string in it.  It's part of a simple program to do some validation in an ETL system. edit: Also, I appreciate that there are likely other ways to solve the problem. I am *not* interested in them except tangentially. I am interested in what's causing the parse error.

Comment: Your code is not working. It only yields `True`, if *all* strings in the list are empty. You need to change your condition to something like `(\acc now -> acc || null now)` to make it work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I try to compile your code with `ghc` I get a type error, not a parse error. That error is because you're trying to call `not` with `foldl` as its first argument and `(\ acc now -> ...)` as the second argument. You need to add a `$` after `not` or wrap the call to `foldl` in parentheses.

<s>You probably got the parser error you mentioned in ghci. In ghci you're not allowed to write definitions the way you would in a file. You're only allowed to enter expressions (which will then be evaluated and the result printed - or executed if it's an IO action) or anything you could write inside an IO `do` block (i.e. `foo <- bar` and `let foo = bar`).</s>

So in ghci you can define variables and functions only by using `let` and you can't define types at all.

The parse error you get is actually caused by `main` where you try to define local variables without `let`. Just add ´let`before`content_hashes = ...`and`is_good_csv = ...` and the parse error will disappear.

Comment: Interestingly, I get " parse error on input `=', regardless of what I do with `not`.

Comment: @Paul: In ghci, right? If so, read the rest of my answer. If not please post your entire file as the code you've shown definitely compiles once you add the `$` (or parentheses) and does not cause a parse error in ghc (with or without the `$` or parentheses).

Answer (score 2):

You get error because function application has highest precedence in Haskell, so

```
not f x
```

reads

```
(not f) x
```

By the way, function you try to implement can be written in more concise way

```
has_empty_strings list = not $ all (/= []) list
```

Comment: @sepp2k: You are right, but when I load this code into ghci (:l some_file_with_this.hs) I get type errors, not parse errors, so I thought that this was the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the problem is, that you lack a pair of parentheses after `not` (You can also use `$`). Additionally, there is the `&&` operator for simple and. You don't have to use extra lists. Replacing the if-then-else with logic makes it easier to comprehend. At last, I use pointless style, because I like it so.

```
has_empty_string = not . foldl (\acc now -> not $ acc == True && now == "") True
```

If you define somethin in the interactive prompt (GHCi) you always have to type `let`, as the prompt is like one big `do` statement.

PS: A simpler way to write this function is

```
has_empty_string = all null
```

But I guess you rather want to have

```
has_empty_string = any null
```

Comment: It'd be `any null`, not `all null`.  Also, this version isn't just simpler to write, it's usually faster, since it is able to short-cut evaluation.

Comment: @Carl Yes, I know. His original code behaves like `all null`, but what he wants is actually `any null`.